# Удалит ли сборщик мусора внешний объект, если объект внутреннего класса всё ещё используется?

Tags: java, коллекции, сборщик-мусора

Имеем код:

```
Iterator<Object> it = new Collection<Object>(){/*...implementation...*/}.iterator();
```

Вопрос: не удалит ли garbage collector тот объект, который я создал для выражения коллекции? Ведь формально ссылки на этот объект у нас нет, но `it (Iterator<Object>)` всё-таки связан с внутренностью нашего объекта безымянного класса.

Другими словами, рассмотрим код:

```
Iterator<Object> it = new Collection<Object>(){             // Строка (1)

    private Object[] array;

    public Iterator<Object> iterator(){
        /*здесь возвращается итератор, ссылающийся на this.array
        + выполняющий свои задачи*/
    } 

    /* + other implementation...*/ 

}.iterator();
```

Тогда удалится ли GC'ом объект созданный в первой строке, ссылки на который у нас объективно нет? `//Строка (1)`

Для особо любящих в комментариях писать псевдо-ответы, вот код того, как именно будет выглядеть мой `iterator`:

```
Iterator<Object> it = new Collection<Object>() { // Строка (1)

        private Object[] array2;

        @Override
        public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Object>() {
                Object[] array;
                {
                    array = array2;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    // Делаем то, что должны
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public Object next() {
                    // Делаем то, что должны
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }

        /* + other implementation... */
}.iterator();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, исходный объект `Collection` (обозначим его `A`) не может быть удалён. Причины таковы:

1. В методе `iterator()` (который, очевидно, вызывается, когда `A` ещё жив) создаётся экземпляр анонимного класса (назовём его `B`). В соответствии с [JLS для SE 8, пункт 15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) анонимный класс эквивалентен внутреннему классу (inner class; не путать с вложенным классом - nested class). Это те, что объявляются в классе просто как `class`, не `static class`.
2. Каждый внутренний класс неявно хранит ссылку на тот объект, в котором он был создан. То если если вы создаёте `B` внутри кода `A`, то экземпляр `B` содержит ссылку на объект `A`. Это верно даже в том случае, если внутри кода `B` никакого доступа к полям/методам `A` нет (более подробный ответ на английском SO из 2009 года [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054363/767632)).
3. А раз свежесозданный `B` содержит ссылку на `A`, и эта ссылка сохраняется в переменной `it`, то пока живёт `it`, живёт и `A`.

В вашем коде, тем не менее, если оптимизатор не постарается очень-очень сильно (а в 2011 году этого [не происходило](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054363/767632), исходный объект типа `Collection` не может быть удалён сборщиком мусора.

Причина такова: когда вы создаёте внутренний класс

А вообще никаких гарантий о том, что объект будет когда-либо удалён, сборщик мусора не предоставляет. Он имеет право ждать, пока закончится память, а дальше начать в авральном порядке подчищать объекты, которые может.